# Why do we use "what" instead of "who" in "what is your name?

Tags: who, what

"What is your name?" instead of "who is your name?" any explanation?

Comment: A name is not a person. Why would _you_ use "who is your name"?

Comment: As general guidance on interrogative pronouns: **Who** = which person. **What** = which thing.

Comment: I recognise a person as being a child, a girl, I know they are the daughter of a friend or acquaintance but I have forgotten her name, I would like to know WHAT her **name** (it) is, not WHO (she) the person is. A "name" is not the same as a person.

Answer (score 2):

"Who" refers to people. "Who is your wife", "Who is your boss?", "Who is the local mayor?", "Who took out the rubbish" are all examples of "who", because they are asking for the person. But a name is not a person, it is an identifier of a person. "What is your name?", "What is your address?", "What is your car's number plate?" are all identifiers, not people.

So, you use WHO when you want to find out which person, otherwise, you use WHAT. The Name of a person is not the person, it is one of several identifiers associated with the person.